# catch route to unexisting function in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

when I redirect to non existing function in controller I get blank page.
it is not 404 Error!

for example I have this controller:

```
public class AccountController
{
  public ActionResult Index()
{
return view();
}
}
```

now, for example i will go to this URL:
http://localhost:2993/Account/sdfjhsdkfjhsdf

I will get a blank page.

my question is, is there a way to catch it ?

thank you

Comment: When you debug, are you getting any exceptions in your code saying "No route in the route table matches the supplied values"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can catch `404` in your `global.asax`. Handle `Application_Error` as shown below -

```
    public void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();
        Server.ClearError();

        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("area", "");
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");

        if (exception.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
        {
            var code = ((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode();
            if (code == 404)
            {
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
            routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", 500);
        }

        routeData.Values.Add("exception", exception);

        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        IController controller = new ErrorController();
        controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
        Response.End();
    }
```

And have your `ErrorController` defined as below. You can have different `Action` methods here to handle different errors like 404, 401 etc.

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you go to Account/asdasdasdasd it is not going to Application_Error. I need to catch it on each controller, how can i do it ? it is like a bad link

Comment: IT has to go to `Application_Error`, unless you have a valid route for the URL. please check your `routeconfig.cs`. I tested above code with a similar url and I was able to capture the error in `Application_Error`.

Comment: And you have to remember that if URL is bad and there is no matching route, request will not go till controller.

Comment: this is my route: routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );   

is it ok ?, because all your suggestions are not working

Comment: With default route it should work. There might be something else in your code which is causing this. Please debug and see if you have any action filter or some other code which is no letting the exception to bubble up to Application_Error.

Answer (score 0):

or you can catch it on End of Request this code how i handle it.

```
  protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (Response.StatusCode)
        {
            case 404:
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.RedirectToRoute("Default", new RouteValueDictionary() { { "controller", "error" }, { "action", "Index" }, { "statuscode", Response.StatusCode } });
                break;
        }
    }
```

add a new controller called as ErrorController

ErrorController.cs

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    // GET: Error
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Error/Index.cshtml

```
<h2>bad request</h2>
```

Comment: if you go to Account/asdasdasdasd it is not going to Application_Error. I need to catch it on each controller, how can i do it ? it is like a bad link

Comment: what you mean each controller?